# How to run a Batch file in a new Window when "start" fails to?

Tags: batch-file

I have attempted to use `start "" batchfile.bat` but it would just open a default CMD Window without any title.
I then tried to do `start CMD call batchfile.bat` with the same results. I've also tried `start "" "%cd%\batchfile.bat"` , yet again, didn't work.

Is there a way to get another batch file to open without using "call"? I'd want it to open in a window on it's own.

Comment: First set of quotes in a Start command line is ALWAYS the window title. Just Put "" after start.

Comment: @acatinlove Now I get the same window with an Empty title and prints "'LocalSTGcmd.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." I am probably doing something wrong again?

Comment: Your code is voodoo based. You should be using `call` not `start` for one.

Comment: @ACatInLove Voodoo based? What does that mean? Yes, "call" does work but runs the lines of code inside the Batch file and I wanted it to open in another Window just because I believe it would look better.

Comment: You'll delete it before it finishes. Plus there is no label called `start` to `goto`.

Comment: That sis because that's only part of the code, the original code is over 600 lines. I tried to use "ping localhost -n 5" to make it wait 5 seconds so that it won't be deleted before it finishes, still nothing.

Comment: `timeout /t 5` is the correct command for that. If you changed your code you need to edit your question and make your edits apparent.

Comment: If those who ask never show their appreciation to those who provide help, where's their incentive? @DarkMesa, please consider marking as accepted, the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of use:

Text file named foo.cmd

```
echo Foo starting
start bar.cmd
pause
```

Text file named bar.cmd

```
echo Welcome to bar
pause
```

This will open bar.cmd in a new Window.
You should make sure the batch file is in the current directory. If the current directory is not the one containing bar.cmd you must use the full path. If both batch files are in same directory you can use:

```
start %~dp0bar.cmd
```

Note this will not work if your path has spaces in it. If you have to put quotes around the path it will think it is specifying the title bar text, not the path to a file.

To find additional start options check output of :

```
start /?
```

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
>
> START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
>         [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
>         [/NODE ] [/AFFINITY ] [/WAIT] [/B]
>         [command/program] [parameters]
>
> ```
> "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
> path        Starting directory.
> B           Start application without creating a new window. The
>             application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
>             enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
>             the application.
> I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
>             to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
> MIN         Start window minimized.
> MAX         Start window maximized.
> SEPARATE    Start 16-bit Windows program in separate memory space.
> SHARED      Start 16-bit Windows program in shared memory space.
> LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class.
> NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class.
> HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class.
> REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class.
> ABOVENORMAL Start application in the ABOVENORMAL priority class.
> BELOWNORMAL Start application in the BELOWNORMAL priority class.
> NODE        Specifies the preferred Non-Uniform Memory Architecture (NUMA)
>             node as a decimal integer.
> AFFINITY    Specifies the processor affinity mask as a hexadecimal number.
>             The process is restricted to running on these processors.
>
>             The affinity mask is interpreted differently when /AFFINITY and
>             /NODE are combined.  Specify the affinity mask as if the NUMA
>             node's processor mask is right shifted to begin at bit zero.
>             The process is restricted to running on those processors in
>             common between the specified affinity mask and the NUMA node.
>             If no processors are in common, the process is restricted to
>             running on the specified NUMA node.
> WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.
> command/program
>             If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
>             the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
>             This means that the window will remain after the command
>             has been run.
>
>             If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
>             it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
>             or a console application.
>
> parameters  These are the parameters passed to the command/program.
> ```
>
> NOTE: The SEPARATE and SHARED options are not supported on 64-bit
>   platforms.
>
> Specifying /NODE allows processes to be created in a way that
>   leverages memory locality on NUMA systems.  For example, two processes
>   that communicate with each other heavily through shared memory can be
>   created to share the same preferred NUMA node in order to minimize
>   memory latencies.  They allocate memory from the same NUMA node when
>   possible, and they are free to run on processors outside the specified
>   node.
>
> ```
> start /NODE 1 application1.exe
> start /NODE 1 application2.exe
> ```
>
> These two processes can be further constrained to run on specific
>   processors within the same NUMA node.  In the following example,
>   application1 runs on the low-order two processors of the node, while
>   application2 runs on the next two processors of the node.  This
>   example assumes the specified node has at least four logical
>   processors.  Note that the node number can be changed to any valid
>   node number for that computer without having to change the affinity
>   mask.
>
> ```
> start /NODE 1 /AFFINITY 0x3 application1.exe
> start /NODE 1 /AFFINITY 0xc application2.exe
> ```
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled, external command invocation through
>   the command line or the START command changes as follows:
>
> non-executable files may be invoked through their file association
>   just
>       by typing the name of the file as a command.  (e.g.  WORD.DOC would
>       launch the application associated with the .DOC file extension).
>       See the ASSOC and FTYPE commands for how to create these
>       associations from within a command script.
>
> When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application,
>   CMD.EXE
>       does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to
>       the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing
>       within a command script.
>
> When executing a command line whose first token is the string "CMD "
>       without an extension or path qualifier, then "CMD" is replaced with
>       the value of the COMSPEC variable.  This prevents picking up CMD.EXE
>       from the current directory.
>
> When executing a command line whose first token does NOT contain an
>       extension, then CMD.EXE uses the value of the PATHEXT
>       environment variable to determine which extensions to look for
>       and in what order.  The default value for the PATHEXT variable
>       is:
>
> ```
>     .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD
>
> Notice the syntax is the same as the PATH variable, with
> semicolons separating the different elements.
> ```
>
> When searching for an executable, if there is no match on any
>   extension, then looks to see if the name matches a directory name.  If
>   it does, the START command launches the Explorer on that path.  If
>   done from the command line, it is the equivalent to doing a CD /D to
>   that path.

Comment: So it simply had to be .cmd instead of .bat, I've just tested it and works as expected, thanks for your Answer.

Comment: According to the documentation it seems .bat should work as well; but .cmd should be used for newer batch files. You can look into a comparison of .bat vs .cmd to find out why, there is some subtle difference how they are handled.